# modifiy HOST_NAME() in sql server

Tags: sql, triggers

I have delete trigger on table, in which I use function HOST_NAME() to retrieve user who executed action then I checked that user exists in User table if not then I throw Raiserror. Action is perform from ASP.NET web application where I dynamically add "Workstation Id" to connection string to have current logged user name in delete trigger.

The problem is that I sometimes must run some scripts manually from SSMS and Host_Name() contains the name of current logged user in sql server, but this user doesn’t have corresponding row in User table and then Raiserror occurred. The question is how can I run delete script from SSMS and doesn’t have Rairserror?

Comment: Just to clarify:  you want a to modify a system function so that a trigger will allow an unauthorized user run delete scripts?  I am truly at a loss.  If you find a way to do this, let me know so that I can find a way to defend against it.

Comment: To clarify: I created this question because I dynamicly add "Workstation Id" to connection string from my web application to have logged user name in delete triger(then I checked name stored in Host_Name() with User table and then I do some sql), but sometimes I have to run some scripts from account that dosen't have corresponding row in User table. After some break I have found sollution I have created my own function in which I check Host_Name() and if user name dosen't exists in User table but name equals xyz then return user from User table. I have hope that you now understood my problem.

Comment: I think so:  you didn't really want to alter the system function, you wanted to wrap it in a custom function that returns the user under which the script should have been run.  Please edit your post accordingly and answer with what you did to get what you wanted.

Comment: @Jason done, sometimes take a break can help to answer the simplest questions:)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is very simple, make your custom function which overriding Host_Name() and if Host_Name() contains user of name XYZ then I return constant name of system user which has corresponding row in User table.

Comment: One thing I'd suggest is that you make a new function entirely and call it.  Overriding system functions means that you break code that expects them to work as documented.